docker bind mount missing files under mounted directory
I been trying to create a bind mount on my docker container, but the files in the bind mount are missing. I think it might have something to do with permission or ownership of files?
I created a store_log dir and there are some files in it. create my bind mount with --mount option, set destination to /app/logs. set container to sleep so I can go inside to debug it
ip-10-249-9-40:store_log buildkite-agent$ ls -la .
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 buildkite-agent  admin   128 Jul 18 00:19 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 root             admin   736 Jul 18 00:19 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root             wheel  8064 Jul 18 00:19 bk-job-log
-rw-rw-rw-   1 buildkite-agent  admin     0 Jul 18 00:19 foo.txt
ip-10-249-9-40:store_log buildkite-agent$ pwd
/my/path/store_log
ip-10-249-9-40:store_log buildkite-agent$ docker run --mount type=bind,source=/my/path/store_log,target=/app/logs my_image sleep 1000


go inside the container. nothing is under the /app/logs folder....
ip-10-249-9-40:~ buildkite-agent$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                                       COMMAND        CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
e13cbc0a54c9   my_image   "sleep 1000"   11 seconds ago   Up 11 seconds             festive_volhard
ip-10-249-9-40:~ buildkite-agent$ docker exec -it e13cbc0a54c9 /bin/bash
root@e13cbc0a54c9:/app# ls
config.json  logs  retriable_error_function.py
root@e13cbc0a54c9:/app# cd logs
root@e13cbc0a54c9:/app/logs# ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 18 00:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jul 18 03:09 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 18 00:27 from_docker.txt
root@e13cbc0a54c9:/app/logs# 

the from_docker.txt is a file I created from inside container (another container) but seems to have persisted which is weird because I though unlike volume bind mount does not persist?
Another weird behavior is that if I try to mount say /bin to /app/bin then it will work
ip-10-249-9-40:store_log buildkite-agent$ ls -la /bin
total 9584
drwxr-xr-x@ 39 root  wheel     1248 Jun 15  2023 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 root  wheel      640 Jun 15  2023 ..
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  1326752 Jun 15  2023 bash
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   135408 Jun 15  2023 cat
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   136960 Jun 15  2023 chmod
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   152800 Jun 15  2023 cp
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel  1153408 Jun 15  2023 csh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   307248 Jun 15  2023 dash
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   168032 Jun 15  2023 date
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   185088 Jun 15  2023 dd
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   151440 Jun 15  2023 df
...

ip-10-249-9-40:store_log buildkite-agent$ docker run --mount type=bind,source=/bin,
target=/app/bin my_image sleep 1000

ip-10-249-9-40:~ buildkite-agent$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                                       COMMAND        CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
925768a338cb   myu_image   "sleep 1000"   5 seconds ago   Up 5 seconds             angry_bardeen
ip-10-249-9-40:~ buildkite-agent$ docker exec -it 925768a338cb /bin/bash
root@925768a338cb:/app# ls /bin
 addpart                   infocmp            rmdir
 apt                       infotocap          run-parts
 apt-cache                 install            runcon
 apt-cdrom                 ionice             savelog
 apt-config                ipcmk              script
 apt-get                   ipcrm              scriptlive
 apt-key                   ipcs               scriptreplay
 apt-mark                  ischroot           sdiff
...
root@925768a338cb:/app# 

any ideas?
edit
maybe worth mentioning this is on a remote machine, the default user is buildkite-agent and the user in container is root. I have tried changing container user with --volume /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro --volume /etc/group:/etc/group:ro --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" but that doesn't seem to help

If the Docker daemon is on a remote system, it will bind mount directories from that remote host system, not your local system; does that explain your behavior?  Note that you can directly docker run --rm -it imagename /bin/bash to get a temporary container running a debugging shell, or even docker run --rm -v ...:/app/logs ls -l /app/logs to just run the file listing as the only container command, which saves a step or two over the docker exec path.
